# Using IPEGA bluetooth gamepad with Retropie

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, emulation, bluez

I'm trying to configure my Ipega PG-9025 with Retropie with no succeed. I made some progress following this link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/608386/using-ipega-bluetooth-gamepad-with-steam-linux) but it only works at Emulation Station menu...

The gamepad stops working in every emulation system and also gives me some problems pairing and reconnecting my device.

Has someone any other advice? Any other try?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution: I installed the last Retropie 3.0 BETA version. It has the bluetooth manager integrated and you will need only some few steps to configure your Ipega PG-9025:

1) First time you'll need to pair your Ipega with Raspberry (once is done, no need to do this anymore).

Check if your dongle is correctly connected:

```
$ hcitool dev
```

Get your adapter number (e.g. `hci0`)

```
$ hciconfig
```

Scan your bluetooth Ipega device:

```
$ hcitool scan
```

Pair your device using the MAC number scanned previously:

```
$ sudo bluez-simple-agent hci# xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

After pairing connect your controller:

```
$ sudo bluez-test-input connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

You will need to trust this device to allow auto-connection after a reboot:

```
$ sudo bluez-test-device trusted xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx yes
```

2) Check if your controller is in the input devices and responds correctly:

Verify there is an input file in e.g. `/dev/input/js0`

```
$ ls /dev/input
```

You can also try your device using the following command:

```
$ jstest /dev/input/js0
```

3) Now you can configure it running the `retropie_setup.sh` script:

```
cd RetroPie-Setup/
sudo ./retropie_setup.sh
```

In the menu, select these options and follow the instructions:

```
SETUP (only if you already have run one of the installations above)

317 Register RetroArch controller
```

And that's all, if you need to use Neo Geo system you will need an extra configuration explained here: https://github.com/petrockblog/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Neo-Geo#controls

It's just test your device (`jstest /dev/input/js0`) and set the button numbers in the correct config file.

Here my Ipega PG-9025 and Nintendo64 demo running in Retropie 3.0 BETA: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmvQi0w0Tec

Comment: Your fantabulous answer helped me through an unrelated issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Great tutorial helped a lot.
I had to start bluetoothd deamon for all this to work

```
sudo bluetoothd
```

Some ppl had problems if thay had sixad service runing and paired with ps3 controler

```
 sudo service sixad stop
```